# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: App with label test could not be found?

Tags: python, django

I have a project structure as

```
myApp/
     apps/
         tests/
              __init__.py
              tests.py
```

The `tests.py` looks as follows

```
from django.test import TestCase

class VideoTest(TestCase):
    def test_video_insert(self):
        self.assertTrue(true)
```

When I try to test this from command-line, I do

```
dirBeforeMyApp$python manage.py test test.VideoTest --settings=myApp.settings.dev
```

I see the following error

```
  File "/Users/user/code/p/virtualenv/myApp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 152, in get_app
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("App with label %s could not be found" % app_label)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: App with label test could not be found
```

What is that I am not doing right here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well your app is called tests, plural.. You might want to avoid that name for obvious reasons anyway